# How can I configure all dependencies before installation?

Tags: software-installation, freebsd, make

I'm new for FreeBSD and currently I'm installing many ports and many of them have a long list of dependencies, I'm tired of wait to finish the installation of one dependency to configure the installation of the next dependency.

Is there a way to facilitate this task ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same question asking myself some time ago, and I wrote an article how you can do this.

First of all, you can run

```
make -DBATCH install clean
```

to accept default configuration for all packages (for dependencies too). 
If you want to configure all dependencies you can run

```
make config-recursive
```

You have to run

```
make config-recursive
```

as many times as needed to configure all dependencies. This happens because while you are  configuring dependencies, these dependencies may have more dependencies that need to be installed and configured.

Then you can run

```
make install clean
```

After all, in case you want to reconfigure or delete configuration you have to run:

```
make rmconfig-recursive
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check [ports-mgmt/portmaster](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=portmaster%288%29&manpath=ports). You can configure and install a port with its dependencies with a simple `portmaster foo/bar`.

Other possibility is [ports-mgmt/portupgrade](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=portupgrade&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+Ports).

Check the [documentation](http://www.dk.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/ports-using.html) too :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way : `make config-recursive`. Downvoting because you didn't bother to use a search engine.